# Code Validator for different programming languages

Tags: web-apps, java, c++, c, validation

Does anybody know any validators for different programming languages? I'm trying to implement it to my web app and I'll need a code validator. I saw fbinfer for Java, C and C++ (but it's not supported on Windows). Or maybe GitHub Copilot if it can do validation? Maybe just to check output results, but I think it's gonna be more complex than that. And by "code validator" I mean to check if your code solution is correct for a given question.

Comment: how are you entering input? sounds like you may need to compile, run, and then check output

Comment: the thing is that my project is in early stages, so I don't exactly know how it would function, but users would probably be able to submit their code and than a validator would check if it works properly (if a validator of this sort exists)

Comment: In the worst case you can probably have a person check the answer, but it isn't a good solution.

Comment: I might suggest [replit](https://replit.com) but idk about the validation, just running